# Approximate the size of the hydrogen atom at temperature $T$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, temperature, atomic-physics

I would appreciate some help on the following problem, because I cant seem to even get started. It's on an old exam on a course that's based on chapters 4-9 on "Modern Physics for Scientists and Engineers" (Quantum mechanics, Hydrogen atom, Atomic Physics, Statistical Physics).

If the electron of a hydrogen atom in the state $n$, then the size (radius) of the hydrogen atom can be approximated as $n^2a_0,$ where $a_0$ is the Bohr radius. In a temperature $T>0$ the electron can be excited to a higher energy level with $n>1$. Suppose you could observe a hydrogen atom for an infinitely long time such that the electron has time to visit every possible energy level. Estimate the size of the hydrogen atom at temperature $T.$

Comment: You would need about $10eV$, that is about a temperature of $10^5 K$ just to have the electron excited to $n=2$. For any realistic temperature in nature, the vast majority of hydrogen atoms will be in the ground state $n=1$ and the size of this does not depend on temperature. The question does not really make much sense.

Comment: @Thomas:  It's still a well-posed question, even if the answer is pretty close to $a_0$ for any "reasonable" temperature.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I beg to disagree. The question seems to be suggesting that there is a one to one relationship between the temperature and the size of the atom. In reality, all levels of an atom will be occupied with a certain probability given by the Boltzmann distribution in thermodynamic equilibrium. There is no such thing as *the* size of the atom. I am astonished that this should have been an exam question based on a textbook. I find it dangerously misleading for the uninitiated reader.

Comment: The mean radial position of a particle in a thermal system makes perfect sense in statistical mechanics (as I mentioned in my post), it just doesn't in this case for a hydrogen atom in free space because the atom ionizes in equilibria.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a very rigorous question since the partition function for a hydrogen atom diverges but I'm guessing we're supposed to just ignore that fact. With that said an electron at temperature $T$ has (very) roughly $kT$ energy so we can very hand-wavingly say

$$kT = E_n - E_1 =\frac{e^2}{2a_0}\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
and so
$$a_0n^2 = \frac{a_0}{1-\frac{2a_0}{e^2}kT}=\frac{a_0}{1-\frac{kT}{E_\infty}}$$

I don't know how good of an approximation this is, but it does diverge as we approach the ionization temperature so that's a plus.

To attempt this more rigorously we would have to compute a quantity like
$$\bar{r}=\frac{1}{Z}\sum_{n}\langle n|\hat{r}|n\rangle e^{-E_n/kT}$$ but unfortunately this is divergent for the hydrogen atom since $E_n \to 0$ for large $n$ and the degeneracy grows as $n^2$.